# How to get the h1 tag from a website in WebDriverIO

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, ui-testing

I am using WebDriverIO to do UI testing. I am trying to get this h1 tag:
[image]

This is my attempt:

```
 it('should get the header of the intro text', () =>{
        const h1 = $('#yui_3_17_2_1_1617935280900_2042');
        expect(h1).toHaveValue("Confidence AI Application: machine learning models provide a systemized approach to assess cash flow risk and opportunity.");
    });
```

The test fails:

```
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1] ✖ should get the header of the intro text
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1]
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1] 1 passing (14.2s)
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1] 1 failing
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1]
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1] 1) should get the header of the intro text
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1] Expect $(`yui_3_17_2_1_1617935280900_2042`) to have property value

Expected: "Confidence AI Application: machine learning models provide a systemized approach to assess cash flow risk and opportunity."
Received: undefined
[chrome 89.0.4389.114 linux #0-1] Error: Expect $(`yui_3_17_2_1_1617935280900_2042`) to have property value
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hey @oo92,
Did my answer help you? If so, please click "Mark Correct" on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
it("should get the header of the intro text", () => {
  const h1 = $("#yui_3_17_2_1_1617935280900_2042");
  expect(h1.getText()).to.eq("Confidence AI Application: machine learning models provide a systemized approach to assess cash flow risk and opportunity.");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you're using the `toHaveValue` method instead of the `toHaveText`.

`toHaveValue` - Checks if an **input element has a certain value**.

`toHaveText` - Checks if an **element has a specific text**.

So, your code should be:

```
 it('should get the header of the intro text', () =>{
   const h1 = $('#yui_3_17_2_1_1617935280900_2042');

   expect(h1).toHaveText("Confidence AI Application: machine learning models provide a systemized approach to assess cash flow risk and opportunity.");
 });
```

Note:

> I'm not sure about selectors, because it looks like they're generated
> on a fly.
> So, please make sure, that they're correct and always the same.